# Why does the inferrer of createDataFrame doesn't create columns this data as strings?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following code shows how a dataFrame is built. It can be seen the dataframe comprises two columns.  Each column has integers and a string in last row.

As a I understand, [createDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) has to analyze datatypes of columns (and in consequence in rows). Then, assume one datatype that can include all rows. In this case, I suppose that columns have to be string datatypes because this type can include numbers and strings.

Therefore, why the resulting dataFrame has columns of long datatype and strings are nullified?

```
# DataFrame construction:
b = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 2),(2, 3), (3, 3), ('test0', 'test1')], ['pepe', 'pepa'], samplingRatio=1)
b.show()


#+----+----+
#|pepe|pepa|
#+----+----+
#|   1|   2|
#|   2|   3|
#|   3|   3|
#|null|null|
#+----+----+
```

After the @ccheneson's suggestion I decided to re-run the code removing the parameter `samplingRatio` and I got exactly the same result. Any idea of why is this happening?

Comment: What is happening if you remove  `samplingRatio` ?

Comment: Thank you. I edit my question, I included the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `samplingRatio` argument is completely ignored when `DataFrame` is created from a local data structure. [It is used only if `data` is a `RDD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e789b1d2c1eab6187f54424ed92697ca200c3101/python/pyspark/sql/context.py#L395). Otherwise data is converted to Java RDD and objects of mismatching types are converted to nulls.

If you pass a `RDD` instead of list Spark will apply schema inference and throw an exception, same as for example in Scala. It happens because Spark doesn't support mixed types and doesn't perform automatic casting.

Why `inferSchema` argument exists at all? It looks like an artifact of deprecated inference on `RDDs` built form the Python dictionaries. But it is just a wild guess.